# Dealing with sparse categories in Pandas - replace everything not in top categories with "Other"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter, data-cleaning

I often come across the following common problem when cleaning the data
there are some more common categories (let's say top 10 movie genres) and lots and lots of others which are sparse. Usual practice here would be to combine sparse genres into "Other" for example.

Easily done when there are not many sparse categories:

```
# Join bungalows as they are sparse classes into 1
df.property_type.replace(['Terraced bungalow','Detached bungalow', 'Semi-detached bungalow'], 'Bungalow', inplace=True)
```

but if for example I have a movies dataset with majority of the movies produced by let's say 8 big studios and I would like to combine everything else under "other" studio, it makes sense to get top 8 studios:

```
top_8_list = []
top_8 = df.studio.value_counts().head(8)
for key, value in top_8.iteritems():
    top_8_list.append(key)

top_8_list
top_8_list
['Universal Pictures',
 'Warner Bros.',
 'Paramount Pictures',
 'Twentieth Century Fox Film Corporation',
 'New Line Cinema',
 'Columbia Pictures Corporation',
 'Touchstone Pictures',
 'Columbia Pictures']
```

and then do something like

replace studio where studio is not in the top 8 list with "other"

so the question, if anyone knows any elegant solution in pandas for this? This is very common data cleaning task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the column to type [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Categorical.html) which has added memory benefits:

```
top_cats = df.studio.value_counts().head(8).index.tolist() + ['other']
df['studio'] = pd.Categorical(df['studio'], categories=top_cats).fillna('other')
```

Comment: this will actually replace top 8 with other

Comment: @DanielLennart durp, you're absolutely right... it's been a long week! I've updated my answer. Apologies again

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen this approach before with Categorical, I will give it a try

Comment: This works as well, thank you. Indeed I can see reduction in memory after converting into Category
`0.749359130859375  MB vs 0.7098274230957031  MB`
for 6000 observations dataset

Comment: To really get the most out of `pd.Categorical`, I think you should make the series categorical *before* you use `value_counts`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with Boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[~df['studio'].isin(top_8_list), 'studio'] = 'Other'
```

Note there's no need to construct your list of top 8 studios via a manual `for` loop:

```
top_8_list = df['studio'].value_counts().index[:8]
```